# How to create an option page for this simple plugin

Tags: plugins, functions, options

I know how to write WordPress plugins but I have no idea how we could create an option page for our plugin. I have read lot of tutorials but I still have no idea about creating option pages.

So just for learning, I want to create an Option Page with one input field "Favicon URL" which will update **FAVICON IMAGE URL** part in the below code:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'show_favicon');
function show_favicon() {
echo '<link href="FAVICON IMAGE URL" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">';
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Copy pate this below code in your functions.php file,

```
<?php add_menu_page('BAW Plugin Settings', 'BAW Settings', 'administrator', __FILE__, 'baw_settings_page', get_stylesheet_directory_uri('stylesheet_directory')."/images/media-button-other.gif"); ?>

<?php
// create custom plugin settings menu
add_action('admin_menu', 'baw_create_menu');

function baw_create_menu() {

    //create new top-level menu
    add_menu_page('BAW Plugin Settings', 'BAW Settings', 'administrator', __FILE__, 'baw_settings_page',plugins_url('/images/icon.png', __FILE__));

    //call register settings function
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_mysettings' );
}


function register_mysettings() {
    //register our settings
    register_setting( 'baw-settings-group', 'new_option_name' );
    register_setting( 'baw-settings-group', 'some_other_option' );
    register_setting( 'baw-settings-group', 'option_etc' );
}

function baw_settings_page() {
?>
<div class="wrap">
<h2>Your Plugin Name</h2>

<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields( 'baw-settings-group' ); ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections( 'baw-settings-group' ); ?>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">New Option Name</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="new_option_name" value="<?php echo get_option('new_option_name'); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Some Other Option</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="some_other_option" value="<?php echo get_option('some_other_option'); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Options, Etc.</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="option_etc" value="<?php echo get_option('option_etc'); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <?php submit_button(); ?>

</form>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

You can find more details here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages

Comment: It will work but it is not a great example for the settings api.... You should use sections, fields and callbacks. It would have been also nice if you actually gave code to what the OP requested ;)

Comment: Also, explain what the code does please. Just pasting a code block is not a good answer. Anyone who reads the answer should know what the code does, including users who is sitll learning.

Answer (score -1):

Create a menu:

```
function ow_plugin_menu(){
    add_menu_page('Name', 'Name', 'administrator', 'ow_admin', 'ow_display_admin_settings', plugins_url( 'icon.ico' ));
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'ow_plugin_menu');
```

and then create a function called **ow_display_admin_settings**